# Typing “Ctrl+R” only lets me type a single character when I'm connected via SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, putty

I connect to my server via ssh (PuTTY). Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at the console. Type a single character.

I can cycle through the previous commands by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> more times.

But if I type another character nothing happens and for some reason I can no longer cycle through previous commands.

It works as expected at a local console though. I’m curious what could be causing this behavior when SSHed into it.

Running stty -a from ssh putty session:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 35; columns 138; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Running stty -a from console session (can't copy paste):
[image]

Comment: Might want to ask this on serverfault or unix.stackexchange if you don't get an answer.

Comment: I don't think this a ssh issue.

you shoud use ESC to end reverse search mode.

You might want to compare key setting by using `stty -a` ( both from console and from ssh).

Comment: Just added results of that command